# Element-api get other entries by id inside a entry.json

Tags: craft3, entry, plugin-elementapi

I have few entry ids from a plugin(donkeytail), and are arranged in an array,

I need to loop through that array and get title, slug, etc of each entry.

$entry->pins = ["106","122","114","134"...]

Endpoint:

```
'single.json' => function() {
        return [
            'criteria' => ['section' => 'home'], 
            'elementType' => Entry::class,        
            'transformer' => function(Entry $entry) {
                  $entryData = (object)[];
                  $entryData->pins = $entry->pins;
                  $entryData->pinnedEntries = (object)[];
                  foreach ($entry->pins as $item) {
                       *Needed Suggestion here to get entry by id ($item)*
                  }
                  return [
                    'title' => $entry->title,
                    'url' => $entry->url,
                    'entryData' => $entryData,
                  ];

        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an entry query to retrieve the entries by their IDs and then use [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to convert that to an associative array of the properties you want to return for those entries.

```php
use craft\elements\Entry;

'transformer' => function (Entry $entry) {
    $entryData = (object) [];
    $entryData->pins = $entry->pins;

    $pinnedEntries = Entry::find()->id($entryData->pins)->status(null)->all();
    $entryData->pinnedEntries = array_map(fn (Entry $entry) => [
        'id' => $entry->id,
        'slug' => $entry->slug,
        'title' => $entry->title,
        'myCustomField' => $entry->getFieldValue('myCustomField'),
    ], $pinnedEntries);
    return [
        'title' => $entry->title,
        'url' => $entry->url,
        'entryData' => $entryData,
    ];
}
```

You can also use an advanced query with a custom `select` statement and use `asArray` to get the associative array directly from the query. That's a bit more involved, but will improve performance in case you run into any bottlenecks.